# Remove items lua/Corona

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Very quick, and probably easy question... but its left me stumped for the last 30 minutes... But how can I remove items from the canvas/screen?

I know this works with removeSelf(), but I'm not quite sure how to use that in my example:

```
display.setStatusBar( display.HiddenStatusBar )

function cat1()
    displayCategory(1)

    print( "clicked 1" ) 
end

function cat2()
    displayCategory(2)

    print( "clicked 2" ) 
end

function cat3()
    displayCategory(3)

    print( "clicked 3" ) 
end

--category display
function displayCategory(cat)

    if (cat == nil) then
        cat = 1
    end

    print( cat )

    if (cat == 1) then
        local item1 = display.newRect(100,100,100,100)
        item1:setFillColor(255,255,0)
    elseif (cat == 2) then
        local item2 = display.newRect(200,100,100,100)
        item2:setFillColor(255,0,255)
    elseif (cat == 3) then
        local item3 = display.newRect(300,100,100,100)
        item3:setFillColor(0,255,255)
    end

end

--category buttons
local catBtn1 = display.newRect(0,0,50,50)
catBtn1:setFillColor( 255,0,0 )
catBtn1:addEventListener( "tap", cat1 )

local catBtn2 = display.newRect(60,0,50,50)
catBtn2:setFillColor( 0,255,0 )
catBtn2:addEventListener( "tap", cat2 )

local catBtn3 = display.newRect(120,0,50,50)
catBtn3:setFillColor( 0,0,255 )
catBtn3:addEventListener( "tap", cat3 )
```

Right now, every time I click on of my buttons, the corresponding item pops up, but doesnt disappear when I click on any of the other buttons. How would I go about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create those itens on start, before the displayCategory function.
Then you set them to not visible, like this:

```
local item1 = display.newRect(100,100,100,100)
item1:setFillColor(255,255,0)
item1.isVisible = false
```

Later you set the proper itens to visible or not as appropriate, in case of item 2 it would be

```
item1.isVisible = false
item2.isVisible = true
item3.isVisible = false
```

Comment: Oooooooooh wasn't aware that lua/Corona supported isVisible parameters... very neat! How's this going to affect memory though, are the pictures (the rectangles will be replaced by images later on) still loaded when they're set to invisible?

Comment: Yes, but loading and unloading stuff (specially with a Garbage Collector present) is bad idea unless you really need the memory back.

Comment: I suppose it wont be a big issue, but good memory management would be nice... Especially considering mobile devices are a little more low on it. I'd ask what you mean by Garbage Collector, but I wouldnt want to derail this thread too much. Thanks for the solution!

Comment: Corona uses Lua, that has a Garbage Collector, that tends to not collect images sometimes, creating and deleting stuff too fast sometimes cause the application to crash.

Prealoding stuff and hiding and showing them when appropriate uses LESS memory.

Comment: Hmm, the more you know... Thanks!